# Unserialize/Deserialize object in reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs

I have an object which is serialized then base64encoded with php and saved in MySQL database table.. 
Now I want to use that table data in ReactJs.

I have base64decoded in react but unable to unserialize it. I tried different npm libraries but not found the solution

PHP Logic :

```
base64_encode(serialize($highlights))
```

Result :

```
YToyOntpOjA7czoxNjoiVGFuYWggTG90IFRlbXBsZSI7aToxO3M6MzM6IldhdGVyc3BvcnQgYXQgVGFuam9uZyBCZW5vYSBCZWFjaCI7fQ==
```

After base64decoded in reactjs the result will be like below.

```
'a:2:{i:0;s:16:"Tanah Lot Temple";i:1;s:33:"Watersport at Tanjong Benoa Beach";}'
```

Please help me to unserialize it

I tested this object online also
https://www.unserialize.com/s/0d18af59-8377-f0a9-5aea-00001982aa2f

Comment: did you tried atob ?

Comment: i think your decoded has some issue when tried it getting this error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded., Kindly add your encoded data it will be much more easy

Comment: Kindly post your encoded data in the question so we can check and help

Comment: updated the question with complete details..

Comment: `serialize` is a bad fit here, better use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php). You could then simply use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the client. If you insist on using `serialize` you would need to write your own parser.

Comment: That PHP Code can't change (stable backend), thats why I am searching solution in reactJs